# Ошибка линкера gcc C

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, mingw, компоновщик

Пытаюсь с помощью winapi проиграть звук. Вот код:
'''#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
PlaySound("bbb.wav",NULL,SND_SYNC | SND_LOOP | SND_FILENAME);
return 0;
}'''

Я более чем уверен, что код правильный. Однако при компиляции возникает ошибка '''C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\cc7CNZmL.o:music.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `__imp_PlaySoundA'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status'''
Компилирую включая -lwinmm.
Такой ошибки у меня не было, пока не начал играться с mingw, устанавливать x32, x64 и т.д. Но позже всё снёс, но ошибка осталась.

Answer (score 0):

- Гуглите `PlaySound winapi`.
- Видите [мануал](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)).
- В нем видите название библиотеки, из которой эта функция:

  > Requirements: Library: Winmm.lib
- Добавляете в конец флажков линковщика `-lwinmm`.

Если флажок там уже есть, то, вероятно вы компилируете под 32 бита, а линковщик находит `libwinmm.a` для 64 бит, или наоборот. Тогда - снести все версии MinGW, которые у вас стоят, и установить заново одну.